# How to get input value from angular material md-datepicker?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

I've the following md-datepicker, that selects a date:

[image: md-datepicker]

How I could to get the date from input value, for use it in another controller?

This is the HTML for the md-datepicker:

```html
<div class="text-center">
<md-datepicker id="sDay" md-min-date="availableMinDate" class="orientationBottom" ng-model="availableCalendar"  md-date-filter="severalDays"></md-datepicker><br>
</div>
```

Comment: You can make data available between controllers using a service. Service in angular are Singletons and if you set a value in them, you can access to it from another controller.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to define `availableCalendar` on the `$rootScope`, that can be accessed by all the scope hierarchy, and then by all the controllers.

Comment: It's not best practice to use $rootScope. As @Danilo Velasquez mentions, services is the way to go.

Comment: You are right. This is an ever working simple solution, but it's the same as creating global variables, and this is bad practice. $broadcast or $emit might be useful as well, depending on the application structure.

Answer (score 0):

To make 2 controllers communicate, you need to use a service.

Create a variable in the said service, create a getter and a setter.

In your first controller, use the setter and send your `availableCalendar` as parameter.

In your second controller, use the getter to get the value, and now you can use it.

If you're new to Angular, an useful link that helped me is [this one.](http://jonathancreamer.com/understanding-angular-js-services-the-easy-way/)